# Loading extremely large JSON file without knowing the schema?

Tags: python, json, postgresql, memory, large-files

I'm trying to load an extremely large JSON file in Python. I've tried:

```
import json
data = open('file.json').read()
loaded = json.loads(data)
```

but that gives me a SIGKILL error.

I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('file.json')
```

and I get an out-of-memory error.

I'd like to try to use `ijson` to stream my data and only pull a subset into it at a time. However, you need to know what the schema of the JSON file is so that you know what events to look for. I don't actually know what the schema of my JSON file is. So, I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to load or stream a large json file in Python without knowing the schema? Or a way to convert a JSON file into another format (or into a postgresql server, for example)?
2. Is there a tool for spitting out what the schema of my JSON file is?

UPDATE:

Used `head file.json` to get an idea of what my JSON file looks like. From there it's a bit easier.

Comment: can you post a sample of your json file?

Answer (score 0):

I would deal with smaller pieces of the file. Take a look at [Lazy Method for Reading Big File in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python). You can adapt the proposed answer to parse your JSON object by object.

Comment: It is a good lead as a general answer, only does not specify how to actually append the separate chunks to the same dataframe object to maintain the same data structure.

Answer (score -1):

You can read in chunks, something like this

```
f=open("file.json")
while True:
    data = f.read(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    yield data
```

Line by line option
    data = []
    with open('file') as f:
        for line in f:
            data.append(json.loads(line))

Also look at
https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-json-tutorial/

Look for more answers with jsonline

Comment: This method doesn't work; when I try to load a chunk of the json file using `json.loads` or `pandas.read_json`, I get errors about it either not being a json object, or in the case of pandas, it being a `ValueError: Trailing data`

Comment: Please try this for jsonline in f:
    yield json.loads(jsonline)

Comment: I get `yield outside function`

Comment: I have appended the answer see if that helps